# Is there any way I can return a value from a loop and continue from where I left off?

Tags: java, loops, return

Is there any way I can return a value from a `loop` and continuing from where I left off ?

In the following snippet, I want to return the current value of `currVm`. But I am unable to do so.

In the innermost loop of the snippet :

```
while(c <= currVm) {
   allocatedVm(currVm);
   c++;
}
```

a function named `allocatedVm` is called. I want to return the value of `currVm` and start again from where I left off. Is there any way out ?

```
@Override
public int getNextAvailableVm() {
    Set<String> dataCenters = confMap.keySet();
    for (String dataCenter : dataCenters) {
        LinkedList<DepConfAttr> list = confMap.get(dataCenter);
        Collections.sort(list, new MemoryComparator());
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        int count = 0;
        while(size >= 0) {
            DepConfAttr dca = (DepConfAttr)list.get(count);
            int currVm = dca.getVmCount();
            int c = 0;
            while(c <= currVm) {
                allocatedVm(currVm); // RETURN currVm
                c++;
            }
            count++;
            size--;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what you are talking about, as you haven't shown us the allocatedVm method. And from where are you returning that value, and what part do you want to resume?

Comment: @RohitJain why do you want `allocatedVm` method ?

Comment: @RohitJain, OP is expecting something like LazySeq(Java 8), Stream(scala)

Comment: @RohitJain and I want to return the value as soon as I call `allocatedVM`

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would probably be to write a method returning an `Iterable<Integer>`. That's not as easy in Java as it is in languages which support generator functions (e.g. C# and Python) but it's still feasible. If the code is short, you can get away with a pair of (nested) anonymous inner classes:

```
public Iterable<Integer> foo() {
    return new Iterable<Integer>() {
        @Override public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                // Implement hasNext, next and remove here
            };
        }
    };
}
```

In your case I'd be tempted to break it into a separate non-anonymous class though, just for simplicity.

Anyway, the point of using `Iterable` is that an `Iterator` *naturally* has state - that's its purpose, basically. So it's a good fit for your requirements.

Another rather simpler approach would be to return *all* of the elements in one go, and make the caller perform the allocation on demand. Obviously that doesn't work well if there could be a huge number of elements, but it would be easier to understand.

Comment: I haven't understood. What do I implement inside `return new Iterator<?> {..}`

Comment: @saplingPro: You need to implement the `Iterator` interface - the `hasNext`, `next` and `remove` methods. (You'll probably want to just throw an exception from `remove`.) You'll probably need to turn all your local variables into instance variables within the iterator. It's not going to be *pleasant* code, but that's just the nature of having to retain state between calls, basically.

Comment: @saplingPro: See my edited answer for another alternative (at the bottom) - we'd need more context to know whether or not that's appropriate though.

Comment: @saplingPro: No, I'm afraid not. We don't really have enough context to know the most appropriate course of action (an iterator or returning a whole collection) and I don't have the time to simply convert your code to an iterator right now. You should try it yourself (study the `Iterable` and `Iterator` interfaces first) and then if you have problems, ask *specific* questions with your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand what you need, but:

if you wish to notify the caller of the method that you've got a value during the running of the method, but don't wish to exit the method just yet, you can use listeners.

just create an interface as a parameter to your function, and have a function inside that will have the object as a parameter.

example:

```
interface IGotValueListener 
  {
  public void onGotValue(MyClass obj); 
  }

public int getNextAvailableVm(IGotValueListener listener)
  {
  ...
  if(listener!=null)
    listener.onGotValue(...);
  }
```

now , for calling the method, you do:

```
int finalResult=getNextAvailableVm(new IGotValueListener ()
  {
  ... //implement onGotValue
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can return from anywhere in your method , by just putting the `return` keyword. If you want to put a functionality to resume ur method from different places then u need to factor ur method in that way. You can use `labels` and `if` statements, set some static variables to mark the last execution place. If your application is not multi-threaded then u need not to worry with the use of static variable synchronization. Also if your method is too big and becoming hard to follow/read, then think about breaking it into smaller ones.

Comment: can you help me with this code ? I want to return `currVm` as soon as I call `allocatedVm(...)`

Comment: @saplingPro put a return statement after allocatedVm(...).